# android screen with multiple sections

Tags: android

I am newbie in android.  I had planned to develop an application which divides screen into two section.  In top section is changes and bottom section is stable, which displays status of the program. Is it possible in android.  If possible which layout is used.

Comment: Wonder if you're trying to implement something like [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html  for the same.

Comment: I am using Android 2.2, is it possible ?

Comment: use Comatibility package for the same.

Comment: Yes, it would support as many devices you want to support, and it also supports both tab and phone, just look at the link.

Comment: is any simple tutorial is available ?

Comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/        http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/12/example-of-using-compatibility-package.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html).